# In Rally SDK 2, are some record types not available for a WSAPIDataStore?

Tags: javascript, rally

When I make a quick wsapidatastore for user story, it works:

```
Ext.create('Rally.data.WsapiDataStore', {
            model: 'User Story',
            autoLoad: true,
            listeners: {
                load: this._onArtifactsLoaded,
                scope: this
            }
        });
```

But if I change it to Artifact, I get an error:

```
Ext.create('Rally.data.WsapiDataStore', {
            model: 'Artifact',
            autoLoad: true,
            listeners: {
                load: this._onArtifactsLoaded,
                scope: this
            }
        });
```

Console says:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'replace' of undefined sdk-debug.js:104071
Ext.define._buildTypeInfo sdk-debug.js:104071
Ext.define.getModels sdk-debug.js:104025
Ext.Array.each sdk-debug.js:956
Ext.define.getModels sdk-debug.js:104024
Ext.define.getModel sdk-debug.js:103985
Ext.define.load sdk-debug.js:104379
(anonymous function)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like there is a error in the model factory.

If you need a workaround you can use this line of code to add artifact as a legit type.

```
Rally.data.ModelTypes.types.artifact = 'artifact';
```